# Cannot change Touchpad settings in openSUSE on HP Pavilion dm4-2015dx 

Tags: drivers, opensuse, synaptics-touchpad

I'm running openSUSE 11.4 on a HP pavilion dm4, with the kernel updated to 3.0.1.

I've had many hardware/drivers issues, but I managed to solve them all except for the Touchpad drivers.

The Touchpad is working with some basic functionality (moving and tapping), but KDE synaptics cant change any Touchpad settings:

[image: Touchpad system settings]

Basically I want to disable the Touchpad on mouse plugin. However other functions (two finger scrolling) would be desirable as well.

Any ideas how I can get it working?

Comment: please do't stuff in tags on the title, make use of the tags field